# Asp.net Button click inside Jquery Modal popup

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, modal-popup

In my asp.net application i have used modal pop up using Jquery. Inside pop up window i have asp.net button. In which i need to write server side code for inserting data to database. But when i click on Button modal pop up is getting closed. I want to keep the modal pop up open when click on the button. 
Below is my html code,

```
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row route-for-reg">
                        <div class="routes-container">
                            <div class="row padding-tb-10">
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="dpPickupLocation" CssClass="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required " data-placeholder="Choose pickup point..." runat="server">
                                        <asp:ListItem>as</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="dpDropLocation" CssClass="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required" data-placeholder="Choose Hinjewadi drop point..." runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="modalPanel" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>


                                    <asp:Button ID="btnViewRoutes" runat="server" Text="View All Routes" OnClick="btnViewRoutes_Click"  CausesValidation="false" />
                                    </ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="accordion-resizer" class="row padding-tb-10">
                            <div id="accordion">
                                    <h3>Pickup</h3>
                                    <div>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblHolderPickup" runat="server" Text="There are no routes available"></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:GridView ID="gridPickUp" runat="server" CssClass="routes-list"></asp:GridView> 
                                    </div>
                                    <h3>Drop</h3>
                                    <div>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblHolderDrop" runat="server" Text="There are no routes available"></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:GridView ID="gridDrop" runat="server" CssClass="routes-list"></asp:GridView> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            <input class="primary-bt" type="button" value="Click to Proceed " />

                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Is there any way to hold the popup window with out closing it when button is clicked.

Thank you in advance
Sangeetha

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using following options

- Put modal content in `UpdatePanel`
- Register clientscript in button click event to open modal popup again.

Answer (score 0):

Since the button is on parent page, it is misbehaving due to postbacks, i could not catch the problem, But you can try creating a new page with the contents with all those click events.

In parent page,

```
 <div class="modal-body">
 <iframe style="width: 710px; height: 450px;" id="ifrmChild" src="NewPage.aspx" runat="server" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
 </div>
```

In Child page, you can have the grids with button control. It is a normal aspx page. But when closing and opening the popup you should use the `parent.FUNCTIONNAME()` call in child page, thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
$('element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
    easing: 'easeOutBack', //uses jQuery easing plugin
    speed: 450,
    transition: 'slideDown'
});
```